# getHistory function not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getHistory()">Refresh</button>
</p>
<br>
<p id="textList">List of texts:</p>
<br>
<p id="textHistory"></p>
<br>
<br>

</div>

<script>

// Gets a list of phone numbers
function getHistory(){
    var success = false;
    // Assemble and send the URL to the Twilio API handler
    //alert(message); // debugging
    var url = 'https://tools.cyntrx.net/GetHistory'
    //var url = 'http://localhost:8000/GetHistory
        
    let response = await fetch(url);
    if (response.ok) { // If HTTP-status is 200-299
      // Get the response body
      let data = await response();
      document.getElementById("textHistory").innerHTML = data;
    } else {
        alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
    }
    if (success) {
        alert("Message sent! (" + displayMsg + ")"); // Alert user of success
    }
}


</script>
```

When I try to run it, the page loads, but when I click on the button I get ReferenceError: getHistory is not defined.

I'm not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You use `await` without declaring the function with `async` keyword. So your function will be:

```
async function getHistory(){
    //Your codes go here
    let response = await fetch(url);
    //Other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `<script>` is not loaded when the `onclick` event is registered. Instead of calling your function in the `onclick`, give your button an id and add an event listener in your script like `document.getElementById("buttonID").addEventListener("click", getHistory);`